# Styled Components: Add sharp corner to bottom-border using CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I need to achieve this green triangular section which has been highlighted in the following screenshot. I'm figuring out ways to achieve it but not sure how to add the "corner" to the bottom border of the container.

This is my expected result.
[image]

My current approach is as follows.  is the container that is black in color. I'm hoping to add the above mentioned green region to the bottom-border of this container.

```
     <AudienceCategories>
        <HeadBar>
          <Logo src={'/static/logos/planto.png'} onClick={null} />
          <CreateAudience>
            <BsPlusCircleFill size={25} />
            <motion.div style={{ marginLeft: 10 }}>
              <SubText color="white">Create Audience</SubText>
            </motion.div>
          </CreateAudience>
        </HeadBar>
        <TextHolder>
          <Heading color="white">Audience Categories</Heading>
          <SubTextContainer>
            <motion.div style={{ width: '400px', display: 'inline-block' }}>
              <SubText color={nativeColors.white}>
                Browse different audience types to see micro-segments and user
                profiles!
              </SubText>
            </motion.div>
          </SubTextContainer>
        </TextHolder>
        <SubTextContainer>
          <motion.div
            style={{
              display: 'flex',
              marginTop: '50px',
              justifyContent: 'center'
            }}
          >
            <SearchInput
              placeholder="Search by user type"
              onChange={onSearchChange}
              value={searchString}
              customWidth={'650px'}
            />
          </motion.div>
        </SubTextContainer>
      </AudienceCategories>
```

Styled Components:

```
const Container = styled(motion.div)``;

const Logo = styled("img")`
    width: 114px;
    height: auto;
    object-fit: contain;
    margin: 20px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
`;

const Variants = styled(motion.div)`
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1000px;
    width: 60%;
`;

const AudienceCategories = styled(motion.div)`
    min-height: 450px;
    background-color: ${nativeColors.pitchBlack};
    color: ${nativeColors.white};
`;

const HeadBar = styled(motion.div)`
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 30px;
`;

const CreateAudience = styled(motion.div)`
    display: flex;
    cursor: pointer;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
`;

const TextHolder = styled(motion.div)`
    display: flex;
    margin-top: -30px;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
`;

const SubTextContainer = styled(motion.div)``;
```

Current attempt:
[image]

Can anyone help me achieve this? I'm not sure how to start.
Thanks!

Comment: Here's a nice reference for creating CSS shapes including *[border shapes](https://css-tricks.com/the-shapes-of-css/)*...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Clip path property of css will solve your problem, below is my code.

Tip: Best [website](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) for making cool clip path edits.

```css
* {
  margin: 0%;
  padding: 0%;
}
.sec1 {
  height: 70vh;
  background-color: black;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% calc(100% - 5vw), 70% 100%, 0 calc(100% -   10vw));
  margin-bottom: -15vw;
}
.sec2{
  height: 15vw;
  background-color: aqua;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 70% calc(100% - 5vw), 100% 30%, 100% calc(100% - 5vw),   70% 100%, 0 calc(100% - 10vw));
}
```

```html
<div class="sec1"></div>
<div class="sec2"></div>
```

Desktop Output:

[image]

Comment: Didn't know such an amazing site already exists!

Answer (score -1):

Just use border-radius: 0;
It wil be automatically removed all radius if you're using any frame or hidden radius or any bugs

Comment: Please read again. The question is asking something different.